# creating conditioned sub-table in R

Tags: r

I'm having the following table (this is just a sample):

```
custNbr   channel   custBranchNbr   totalTransactions
  1         Web        901           7
  2         store      903           5
  3         Cel        901           10
  etc...
```

and I'd like to create "sub_table" which summarize the number of transactions in each custBranchNbr conditioned on the specific channels (Web+Cel only); something like this:

```
custBranchNbr  sum(totalTransaction)
    901             17
```

I know how to use conditional sum (like this: `sum(DF[which(DF[,1]>30 & DF[,4]>90),2])`), but I don't know how can I implement this to get the "sub-table" I described above.

your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

use the aggregate function

```
sub_table <- aggregate(custBranchNbr, df[df$channel %in% c('Web', 'Cel'), ], sum)
```

Comment: Hi, for some reason (I checked, and it's not a typo error) I'm getting an error that _"arguments must have same length"_. my command line is: `primiumSubTable=aggregate(primium$Branch_Nbr,primium[primium$ChannelType %in% c('Web','Cel'),],sum)`

Answer (score 0):

we can also do this with `library(dplyr)`:

```
df %>% filter(channel %in% c("Web", "Cel") %>%
                  group_by(custBranchNbr) %>%
                  summarise(sum_totalTransactions = sum(totalTransactions))
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  custBranchNbr sum_totalTransactions
          <int>                 <int>
1           901                    17
```

Answer (score 0):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[channel %chin% c('Web', 'Cel'),  .(Sum = sum(totalTransaction)).( , custBranchNbr]
```